# Losing CSS styling upon printing

Tags: javascript, css, printing

I am using a style sheet to properly print out a webpage. The webpage has fields sat next to each other but upon printing these fields no longer sit next to each other but instead cascade down the sheet. I have created a style sheet but I'm not sure exactly how that is supposed to stop this from happening unless I hard code into the style sheet what I want to happen. Unfortunately I can't do that because I need to print out several different pages that have different layouts.
Is there any way to fix this?

```
function removeLinks(printDiv) {
            var all_links = document.getElementById(printDiv).getElementsByTagName("a");

            for (var i = 0; i < all_links.length; i++) {
                all_links[i].removeAttribute("href");
            }
        }

        function printdiv(printDiv) {
            var divCaseNote = document.getElementById(printDiv);
            var oldstr = document.body.innerHTML;
            var oldTitle = document.title;

            if (divCaseNote != null) {
                divCaseNote.style = "padding: 20px;";
                innerHTML = divCaseNote.innerHTML;
            }

            removeLinks(printDiv);

            var headstr = "<html><head rel=\"stylesheet\" media=\"all\" link href=\"/CSS/style.css\"/><title> </title></head><body>";
            var footstr = "</body>";
            var newstr = document.all.item(printDiv).innerHTML;
            document.body.innerHTML = headstr + newstr + footstr;
            document.title = oldTitle.replace(" - View Case Note", "");

            window.print()

            document.body.innerHTML = oldstr;
            document.title = oldTitle;
```

EDIT: A snippet of the html output of this function. It holds all the correct divs for the columns but instead of printing the columns side by side they print cascading down the page.

```
<div class=\"view-value\" style=\"border-left: none;\">
   Jerry</div></div></div>
   <div class=\"col-md-3\"><div class=\"media-body\">   
      <div class=\"view-label\">Participant's Last Name</div>
        <div class=\"view-value\" style=\"border-left: none;\">Field</div>
```

What it should look like
[[image: What it should look like][1]]

What it actually looks like after printing
[image: What it actually looks like after printing]

Comment: Just a couple of comments to start: you are using document.all which is deprecated. Is there a reason for using this rather than the getElementById for example? Also you are completely removing any inline styling from the element. We can't know whether this matters without seeing some HTML. Could you show us some example HTML so we can see the structure and typical CSS applied to the element you want to print

Comment: How do I keep inline styling? I can swap the document.all to get element by id

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the inline styles are getting obliterated by this statement:

```
            divCaseNote.style = "padding: 20px;";
```

which removes all the style attribute and replaces it with just the padding.

To add/alter the padding but nothing else you want to change just that property so try:

```
            divCaseNote.style.padding = "20px";
```